# Remove class when click another button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm figure out for how to remove class `selected` when clicking other button. I've made code below but still not working. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

The case study, I have 2 choice boxes. box 1 and box 2. each box has 2 options. When click on box 1 option 1 and move to box 1 option 2, it works fine. But when I click box 2 option 1, the options in box 1 should not change. So there will be 2 buttons that have the selected class, namely box 1 choice 2 and box 2 choice 1

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box-1 button, .box-2 button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.box-1 button, .box-2 button').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
button{
  border:none;
  background-color:#1f45;
  padding: .5rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.box-1{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button.selected{
  background-color: #578889;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Box 1 Choice</h3>
<div class="box-1">
  <button>Box 1 Option 1</button>
  <button>Box 1 Option 2</button>
</div>

<h3>Box 2 Choice</h3>
<div class="box-2">
  <button>Box 2 Option 1</button>
  <button>Box 2 Option 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.not(this)` to exclude button which is clicked and remove `selected` class from there

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('div').find('button').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #1f45;
  padding: .5rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

button.selected {
  background-color: #578889;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-1">
  <button>Box 1 Option 1</button>
  <button>Box 1 Option 2</button>
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  <button>Box 2 Option 1</button>
  <button>Box 2 Option 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question content. the case study, I have 2 choice boxes. box 1 and box 2. each box has 2 options. When click on box 1 option 1 and move to box 1 option 2, it works fine. But when I click box 2 option 1, the options in box 1 should not change. So there will be 2 buttons that have the selected class, namely box 1 choice 2 and box 2 choice 1 @Swati

Comment: Why don’t you give separate Id”s to those buttons, by doing this you can easily identify them and can make separate action for each button

Comment: @PranavPatel That depends on op .

Comment: @Swati ,yeah that is right,I beg your pardon on this as your stack score says you are  good programmer, but it is good practice na ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
     $('button').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected')
  });
});
```

it will work!

Comment: please consider using a runnable stack snippet (`<ctrl> + m` while editing)

Comment: i don't know this until u say, thanks for your tip @Tibebes.M

Answer (score 1):

remove `selected` class before adding it to `button`
You to make it work in different wrappers you need `$(this).parent()`, and then search for call `selected`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
button{
  border:none;
  background-color:#1f45;
  padding: .5rem 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

button.selected{
  background-color: #578889;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-1">
  <button>Box 1 Option 1</button>
  <button>Box 1 Option 2</button>
</div>

<h3>Box 2 Choice</h3>
<div class="box-2">
  <button>Box 2 Option 1</button>
  <button>Box 2 Option 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question content. the case study, I have 2 choice boxes. box 1 and box 2. each box has 2 options. When click on box 1 option 1 and move to box 1 option 2, it works fine. But when I click box 2 option 1, the options in box 1 should not change. So there will be 2 buttons that have the selected class, namely box 1 choice 2 and box 2 choice 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the class from every button and after that to the clicked button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $('button').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Comment: please consider using a runnable stack snippet (`<ctrl> + m` while editing)